# convert DivX (and other formats) to DVD video under linux

Tags: ubuntu, video, conversion, dvd, divx

Can anyone recommend a DVD format converter which runs under ubuntu 9.04? I need to convert a DivX format into a regular DVD, but converters for other formats would be helpful (to me and others) as well. Free software would be nice but non-free is okay too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these should do the trick:

- ffmpeg
- mencoder
- vcl

They are commonly included in the repos of all the major distros.

ffmpeg and mencoder are used as a backend by several linux apps, so you can either use some CLI ninja skills or do it via GUI as for example [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/yameg/).

AFAIK, although VLC is best known in the form of GUI application you can also use it from command-line.

You also have the option to use video editing software like [OpenShot](http://www.openshotvideo.com/) or [Kino](http://www.kinodv.org/) to do your editing first and then save it as mpeg-2 files.

Once you are all set up with your files, you can then create a regular DVD to be played in domestic appliances with - amongst others - [dvdauthor](http://dvdauthor.sourceforge.net/).

Finally there is a package called [videotrans](http://videotrans.sourceforge.net/), which is a collection of scripts and tools for creating DVD's. Here's the project brief description:

> videotrans is a set of scripts that allow its user to reformat existing movies into the VOB format that is used on DVDs.
>
> Furthermore, videotrans supplies programs which allow its user to create a complete DVD, including selection menus which allow the viewer to choose which movie he/she wants to see, if more than one movie fits onto a DVD.

Hope this helps!