# Any 'ConvertXtoDVD'-like software for ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, dvd, authoring

Im looking for a software to convert any video files (avi, mpeg, etc) in a full-compatible DVD (that can be read on the mosts of dvd reader).

For windows, i bought [ConvertXtoDVD](http://www.vso-software.fr/products/convert_x_to_dvd/) and is really good, especially becose let you customize the chapters, join many files in one, edit the titles, etc.. in a really easy way.

There is something like for Ubuntu?

Comment: ConvertXtoDVD works pretty good under wine, has worked well several times for me ;)

Comment: Thanks, i'll try under wine, but i'll prefer something full-linux compatible, im not an ubuntu expert and wine somtime proc some errors.. and i take looong time to understand ho to fix it (that's why im totally switch on ubuntu, want to learn it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to use ConvertXtoDVD as well.

On Linux I've found [DeVeDe](http://www.rastersoft.com/programas/devede.html) to be the best alternative.

Comment: +1 DeVeDe is awesome. I always use it for just this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

DeVeDe is a great tool - super simple.  One area it's weak in is creating DVD menus.

[Dvdauthor](http://dvdauthor.sourceforge.net/) is a command line utility that has a ton of capability.  [Q DvdAuthor](http://qdvdauthor.sourceforge.net/) is a simple gui that handles the complexity of writing dvdauthor input files & invoking dvdauthor for you.  It can't do everything, dvdauthor does, but it's easier if you're new to dvdauthor.  It includes a template dialog to help make menus.  The website has some [menu templates](http://qdvdauthor.sourceforge.net/templates.html).

[image: q dvd author]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the software you are mentioning as I am not a Windows user, but have a look at [this question/answer](https://superuser.com/questions/73996/convert-divx-and-other-formats-to-dvd-video-under-linux/74009#74009)... I believe it might contain some useful information for your case.